# Linear dependency proof with LES

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, systems-of-equations

Problem:

Let $V = \mathbb{R}^n$ be a vector space and let $v_i$ be vectors for indices $i \in \{1,\dots,n+1\}$.

Show that for $i \leq i \leq n+1$ there exist scalars $\lambda_i \neq 0$ so that for at least one $i$

$$ \lambda_1v_1 + \lambda_2v_2 + \dots + \lambda_{n+1}v_{n+1} = 0 $$

holds.

Question:

I would like to know, how to split this equation in a linear equation system, as well as in more generally how to find the proof in this. Essentially what I understand from this, you put this into a linear equation system and try to shorten it down with the help of the Gauß-Algorithm. So that i can read from the rank of the matrix that there has to be at least one scalar so that this equation holds.

Comment: Any linear map $\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ must have a non trivial null space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A linear equation system is:

$$\mathbf V \mathbf \lambda = \mathbf 0$$
or
$$ \left( \array{v_{1,1} & v_{2,1} &\cdots &v_{n+1,1} \\
v_{1,2} & v_{2,2} &\cdots &v_{n+1,2} \\
\vdots & \vdots &\ddots &\vdots \\
v_{1,n} & v_{2,n} &\cdots &v_{n+1,n}} \right)\left(\array{\lambda_1 \\
\lambda_2 \\
\vdots \\
\lambda_{n+1}}\right) = \mathbf 0
$$

where $\mathbf V$ is the matrix with $n+1$ columns and $n$ rows made up of $v_1, v_2, \cdots , v_{n+1}$ and $\mathbf \lambda$ is the vector with unknown elements $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \cdots,\lambda_{n+1}$.  Thus you have $n$ equations and $n+1$ unknowns so there will always be a non-trivial solution.  You can apply the algorithm to find one.

Another way to think of it is that if there were $n+1$ linearly independent vectors in a vector space then the space must have dimension $n+1$ or higher.  We know $\mathbf R^{n}$ is $n$-dimensional, so it cannot have $n+1$ linearly independent vectors.

Comment: I got a question, how would the Matrix look like once you apply the Vector towards it ? I still can't seem to reach right now to the Gauß-Algorithm part.

Comment: You can apply the Gauss algorithm to the matrix above.  For a detailed description have a look at Wikipedia, [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination). In this case, because there are more columns than rows, when you reach the end of the elimination there will be two coefficients left, resulting in $\alpha_i\lambda_i + \beta_j\lambda_j=0$ for two elements $\lambda_i, \lambda_j, i\neq j$.  This elementary equation *always* has non-zero solutions, which then means the columns cannot be linearly independent.

Comment: Sorry if i have to commend on this again, i am still quite confused, at what the final Matrix should look like for one of the results to be correct. I don't know how to use the Gaussian elimination onto this specific matrix. It might just look too complex for me on how to eliminate the entries to get to the desired result.

Comment: I am not sure I can explain better than the Wikipedia Example.  Maybe you can try a simple numerical example;  often you will find you gain an understanding just working through the numbers.